# Find the largest prime divisor of any predetermined number without using / (division) and % (remainder) in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I have some task:

> You can use basic control structures–sequence, branch, loop, as well as addition, subtraction, and multiplication. You **cannot use division**: this module is designed to run on microcontrollers. Create an src/1948.c file which takes a number into **stdin** after compilation and launch, and calculates its largest prime divisor.

[image]

I can't figure out how this can be done without using devisor and reminder. Please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That will end up being quite expensive, since you need to use that repeated subtraction function in a loop to test whether a number is prime, and then again to test whether it's a factor of the input.

Comment: What does "predetermined" mean in this context? What's the difference between finding the largest prime divisor of an integer and finding the largest prime divisor of a predetermined integer? Also, what outputs would you expect for an input of `1`, or `0`, or `-1`?

Comment: I'm not indoctrinated with all the peculiar lore concerning embedded microcontroller programming, but can someone who is say whether this is a reasonable exercise or not?  Division may be expensive, meaning you want to avoid it when possible, but in a problem where division is unavoidable (like prime factoring), will a naive programmer's clumsy emulation of division ever be more efficient than whatever emulation the compiler emits when you write `/` or `%`?

Comment: What does a translator make of the last paragraph before and after your 2022/08/08 edit when translating into your first language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you could just write a division function and then call that to do division.

Alternatively, you can write a square root function and use (a+b)(a-b) = a<sup>2</sup> - b<sup>2</sup>.  After removing the factors of 2, start with the smallest a >= sqrt(N), and then check every a<sup>2</sup> - N to see if it's square.

A division function can be as easy as this:

```
// only works for num >= 0 and den>0
divide(num, den):
    if (num < den):
        return 0
    q = divide(num, den*2) * 2
    r = num - q*den
    return r >= den ? q + 1 : q
```

Square root is just a little more complicated:

```
// only works for n >= 0
sqrt(n):
    return sqrtScaled(n,1)

// return floor(sqrt(n)/scale).  Must have n >= 0, scale > 0
sqrtScaled(n, scale):
    if (n < scale*scale):
        return 0
    q = sqrtScaled(n, scale*2) * 2
    test = (q+1)*scale
    return test*test <= n ? q+1 : q
```

Answer (score 3):

**By the Sieve of Eratosthenes**

Suppose the predetermined integer is *N*.
Negate *N* if negative.
Store *N* as the 'highest prime divisor'.
Allocate an array with *(N >> 1) + 1* elements and fill with 0.

Start with the first prime 2.
Check off every multiple of the prime in the array (with an addition loop).
Continue finding multiples right up to *N*.
If it hits *N* exactly, store this prime as the 'highest prime divisor'.
Find the next prime.
This will be the next unchecked element in the sieve - the array.
But if you've passed the end of the array then you are done.
Otherwise repeat as you did for the previous prime.

Comment: just need to add `N/2` bits is needed for the Sieve so `N/16` bytes which might be a problem if N is too big as this is for MCU ... the table has to be encoded as bit-map ... naive `bool SoE[N>>1];` might be (depends on compiler) much bigger then `BYTE SoE[N>>4];`...

Comment: @Spektre yes a bit array can be used, and further efficiency of not handling any even numbers again halves the sieve size. I was just outlining the algorithm.